# Where to go from here? How to Progress?

Tags: film, sound-design, sound-editing

I'm currently a sound editor and sound designer in the Los Angeles area and I've worked on various shows that have aired on different networks.

I'm trying to find a way to break into working on bigger TV shows and eventually larger budgeted feature films. And I know there isn't a sure-fire way to go about it but any suggestions would be of much help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: this response was to the original iteration of the question.

To be perfectly honest, this question rubs me the wrong way - a first actually.

What rubs me the wrong way, and this is merely an observation of principal and NOT a judgement of personality/character... is that **I sense a lack of gratitude**, a lack of appreciation for what has been had and materialized thusfar.  At this young in ones career (I did look you up on IMDB), those are outstanding projects to be working on let alone garnering nominations for as well.  It truly is a great start.  A greater start than even some who work for their entire lives in this industry might be able to achieve recognition for.  Again, not a judgement - just an observation of the facts.  Emmys and MPSEs aren't some Jelly-of-the-month club award either, they carry some professional weight and have the potential to open doors for you.

I am a big believer of both karmic debt as well as allowing ones credibility to promote itself through their body of work and dedication to the craft - do good work, the work speaks for itself and opens you doors.  To this end, I find that when I appreciate what I do have, and strive to do good deeds for others (whether it be keeping my head down on the job at hand, always providing my best effort, sharing ideas with others and not squandering them to myself, etc), the doors open themselves through the laws of attraction, and some amazing things have happened within my own journey - relationships forged, coincidences, connections I never know existed, ways into landing a certain gig I never even expected was possible and felt like luck.

This is a very small world in this industry, so incredibly small with each passing day, and (as I've said many times) word gets around fast, both good and bad, positive and negative.  As does your body of work and your reputation, your appreciation and gratitude for what you have and being known for being kind and generous in return.  Some of the top-regarded talent I have had the opportunity to meet are some of the nicest and most humble people I know.  They are hungry for the gig yes, but do not seek recognition(some even shy away from it), are not greedy, and most of all, are extremely grateful for what they have in their "feather cap" and are willing to share with others in kind, especially willing to share and help those who share their same values and desire to work humbly and grow into their craft.

This is how one moves forward.  Always putting out their best effort in out body of work, always having the desire to grow, always being humble and truthful, ALWAYS possessing the gratitude for what they have.  What shows we have worked on or awards or nominations garnered, one earns those - they cannot be taken away.  **But** the very second one loses gratitude for these things very things, they CAN actually be taken away by the outside, universal circumstances of life.

And once again, this is merely observation of principal and NOT a judgement of personality/character.  One in which I truly feel I need to share my thoughts on because of how adverse the question makes me feel.

Comment: Actually Emmy's and Golden Reels can be kind of like a Jelly of the Month Club.
If a show wins everybody on the crew gets one. I've got an Emmy and seven Golden Reels. 
The best most contributing editor on the show gets the same award as the hack who was brought on and whose reel bounced.
If someone is trumpeting their awards I always take it with a grain of salt. Not to say the awards are meaningless. They can mean something important or they can mean nothing. I've also worked on four (or is it five) films that have won the Oscar where I got a thank you on TV and a pat on the back ...

Comment: @Chris I definitely agree with what you say - you bring up some very valid points of consideration too with regard to the team dynamic, the pros and cons how there is some degree superfluousness to awards and honors. It's exactly why I'm all about the work and not about the recognition, as you said best, "your reputation will precede you". Unfortunately this answer is now grossly out of context to the original question, so I can completely understand where the disconnect can be seen.

Answer (score 2):

Hard work, talent and a good attitude ...

Your reputation well precede you. If you are good people will find out.

Comment: Crap, do I really need all three? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Good question Jessey.  I am in no way any further than yourself by the sounds of it but it all just seems to be about who you know and if people like working with you (apart from having the goods to begin with).  A friend of mine just got picked up by a big post production house as head of SFX and she's much younger than I am, but really very talented.  From what I can tell it started off by one guy hiring her for all of his projects.  From moving from city to city for each film, she at one point worked in the studio in which ultimately offered her the position overseas.  So again, I don't know but I think personal relations is a huge part of any success.  At the same time a good director friend has said he can track all of his current work back to one single guy he met at uni.  So, I think nurture what relations you have around you and people will be attracted to you in turn.  Hope that helps!